# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string name'

Tags: python, django

I am making an API module which saves weather data to my Django database by running a single Django management command, which retries all the data from a source API. I've created a model 'weather data' which has all the required datatypes. I've a management command written which directly saves data to my database.

The snippet of management command and models.py is shown below.

```py
def handle(self,*args,**kwargs):
        for city in input_file:
            city_name = city.strip()
            print(city_name)
            full_api_url =  api + city_name + '&mode=json&units=' + unit + '&APPID=' + user_api
            full_wet_url =  weather_api + city_name + '&mode=json&units=' + unit + '&APPID=' + user_api


            try:
                data = requests.get(full_api_url).json()
                dta = requests.get(full_wet_url).json()
                city_id = dta["id"]
                longitude = dta["coord"]["lon"]
                latitude= dta["coord"]["lat"]
                for dt in data["list"]:
                    temp        = dt["main"]["temp"]
                    temp_min    = dt["main"]["temp_min"]
                    temp_max    = dt["main"]["temp_max"]
                    pressure    = dt["main"]["pressure"]
                    sea_level   = dt["main"]["sea_level"]
                    grnd_level  = dt["main"]["grnd_level"]
                    humidity    = dt["main"]["humidity"]
                    weather     = dt["weather"][0]
                    main        = weather["main"]
                    description = weather["description"]
                    clouds      = dt["clouds"]["all"]
                    wind_speed  = dt["wind"]["speed"]
                    wind_deg    = dt["wind"]["deg"]
                    dt_txt      = dt["dt_txt"]
                    wd = weatherdata(city_name,city_id,latitude,longitude,dt_txt,temp,temp_min,temp_max,pressure,sea_level,grnd_level,humidity,main,description,clouds,wind_speed,wind_deg).save()


                print ("Success")

            except Exception as e:
                print (e)
                pass
```

```py
class weatherdata(models.Model):
    city_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    city_id     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latitude    = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    longitude   = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    dt_txt      = models.DateTimeField()
    temp        = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_min    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_max    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    pressure    = models.FloatField(null = False) 
    sea_level   = models.FloatField(null = False)
    grnd_level  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    humidity    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    main        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clouds      = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    wind_speed  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    wind_degree = models.FloatField(null = False)
```

if I try executing 'python manage.py theweather'(the weather being the name of management command file), am getting an error stating:

```
nantapur
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Anantapur'
Chittoor
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Chittoor'
Kakinada
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Kakinada'
```

for all the city names in headquarters.csv file.
what is the solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use *named parameters*, using positional ones is "unstable" since if you later add some field, then it might go wrong. Note that the first parameter is here the implicit primary key:

```
wd = weatherdata.objects.create(
    city_name=city_name,
    city_id=city_id,
    latitude=latitude,
    longitude=longitude,
    dt_txt=dt_txt,
    temp=temp,
    temp_min=temp_min,
    temp_max=temp_max,
    pressure=pressure,
    sea_level=sea_level,
    grnd_level=grnd_level,
    humidity=humidity,
    main=main,
    description=description,
    clouds=clouds,
    wind_speed=wind_speed,
    wind_deg=wind_deg
)
```

That being said, I'm not sure the modeling is good here, it contains a lot of data duplication.

Note that class names are usually written in `CamelCase`, so it should be `WeatherData`, *not* <s>`weatherdata`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Willem Van Onsem , I've declared wd before using .save() but the error still remains the same.

Comment: @AkashKumar: then it thus means that a field (like `city_id`, does not contain a numerical id, but a string). You should debug it by checking the values you retrieve from parsing.

Comment: the error specifically states"invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Chittoor' " .the retrieved data for this particular city is " Chittoor 1274033 13.22 79.1 2019-08-12 15:00:00 30.1 26.31 30.1 1005.39 1005.39 948.07 68 Rain light rain 99 5.05 292.743 " . so that's exactly where I am struck

Comment: @AkashKumar: if the first column is the `'id'`, then it makes perfectly sense that that raises an error, since the id is then `'Chittoor'`, and evidently that is not numerical data.

Comment: but the first column contains `'Chittoor'` which is CharField second column is the one which contains `'id'`.

Comment: @AkashKumar: the question is not in what order the elements are in the database, but in the CSV file...